# H2 database "Error while renaming file" when updating a table

Tags: h2

I'm using the latest version of H2, i.e. version 1.3.150 and I get a org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException when updating a VARCHAR2.

- The SQL statement is a very simple

  `UPDATE STAMP_TABLE SET DESCRIPTION='a bit of text' WHERE STAMPID='s/1'`
- and The table itself has nothing special, just a bunch of VARCHAR2 and a BLOB
- It works the first time round and fails the second time with the error message:

  `Error while renaming file "C:\my\local\path\1.t6.lob.db" to "C:\my\local\path\1.temp.lob.db"`
- the method that uses the SQL statement is below:

  ```
  public void updateStampDescription(StampId stampId, String description) throws SQLException {

      PreparedStatement stmt = null;

      try {

          stmt = conn.prepareStatement(UPDATE_STAMP_DESCRIPTION);
          stmt.setString(1, description);
          stmt.setString(2, stampId.getId());

          logger.debug("SQL statement: " + stmt.toString());

          stmt.execute();

      }
      catch(SQLException ex){
          logger.error("Error while updating table " + STAMPS_TABLE_NAME + ", description column: " + ex.getMessage() );
          ex.printStackTrace();
          throw ex;
      }
      finally {
          if(stmt!=null) stmt.close(); // Also closes the ResultSet
      }

  }
  ```

Any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: Could you also post the stack trace (including the root causes)? Is this a Windows machine? I know about problems when trying to rename files that are still open (basically, you can't on Windows). In any case, this problem can be resolved by upgrading the database to the new format where BLOBs are stored within the database instead of external files - see http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#upgrade_backup_restore

Comment: @Thomas, Good point about Windows, cause I haven't seen this happen on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question:

Actually, the project was sitting on a Dropbox folder and the files were being used by Dropbox at the time, and hence could not be renamed as H2 wanted.

Comment: It's good to know what the problem was, thanks! For H2, the plan is to get rid of those external files where possible. H2 version 1.3 doesn't create separate files for BLOB and CLOB data any longer. There are still some temp files created in certain cases (large queries, large transactions), it will take a bit longer to get rid of those.

Comment: Version 1.3 is indeed a big improvement upon this issue, even there are still some temp files left, it's good to know you guys are working on it.